# Two codeigniter project in localhost when use same time i got session issue

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

We have issue of two different project with session in Codeigniter. In **localhost** server when one codeigniter project already running and after that when second project start, at that time already running project session destroy.

**So, we need to help for that, what is reason behind this issue ?**

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I have one project running in my localhost with session functionality, after that start another project in localhost using session functionality then first project session automatically destroy. This is my issue. are you getting my point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change in **config.php**:

**FROM**:

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';

**TO**:

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session1';